# Cucumber takes more time to build when making changes in step-definition, feature file and pom.xml file in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Whenever I make changes in step-definition, feature file and pom.xml file in Eclipse IDE, cucumber takes more time to build. It is taking more than 5 mins for each build.

Can someone tell me how to avoid this issue permanently? For the time-being, I disabled build automatically option in project  menu bar.

Is this issue occurring due to eclipse cucumber plugin? If I switch to another IDE (IntellijIDEA), my problem will be resolved?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems we have issues in the Cucumber eclipse plugin in the Eclipse IDE. Due to the cucumber eclipse plugin, project is being built more time.